# Use HTML 5 API classList in Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out if I'm possible to use the new HTML 5 API functions within Angular, specifically within an Angular directive.

I'm trying to add a class to my element, which works fine with jQuery's `addClass` function:

```
function addClass($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      el.addClass('new-class');
    }
  }
}
```

But I was wondering if I'm able to use the `JS` library instead and make use of the `classList` function, like so:

```
el.classList.add('new-class');
```

Does anyone know if this is possible at all?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`el` is an [angular element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) which would have an `addClass` method that you can use directly, so your existing code would still work without jQuery being referenced.

If you want to access the raw DOM element then you can get it by indexing the angular element, for example:

```
el[0].classList.add('new-class');
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use your controllers scope to add classes. Write a function that concats your classes and bind it to the `ng-class` directive.

```
<a ng-class="concat(currElement)">Link</a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.currElement = ["class","otherclass"];
$scope.concat = function(classes) {
    var c = "";
    angular.forEach(classes,function(value){
        c = c.concat(value + " ");
    });
    return c;
}
```

Now you can push data or remove from `$scope.currElement`.

Comment: I understand this. But I want to do this inside an Angular directive.